# FullSimplify-ing automatically

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Is it possible to make Mathematica `FullSimplify` all expressions automatically? I am performing symbolic computations and I am trying to avoid writing `FullSimplify` around every line of code.

### UPDATE:

In light of some of the comments, I thought it would be worthwhile to provide more context regarding the application I had in mind.

It is a common situation while manipulating well-behaved functions, such as symbolic polynomials of several variables, that one is interested in performing standard, simple yet potentially lengthy computations. These could include taking derivatives and cross products, normalizing, or forming and inverting matrices. Some of these operations involve square roots and absolute values, which do not simplify when the variables are symbolic. Multiple layers of these processes can produce very long formulas, obscuring patterns that would otherwise be evident.

The goal is to use Mathematica to experiment with different combinations of operations, observe the resulting formulas and adjust, without having to constantly specify simplification and assumptions. From the comments, it seems that a good way of doing this would be:

`$Post=FullSimplify;`

`$Assumptions=...;`

`...work space...`

`$Post=.;`

`$Assumptions=True;`

What would be the correct way of adding `TimeConstrained` to `$Post` at the beginning? As @Nasser suggested this is a good idea if one is worried about `FullSimplify` taking too long.

### 2nd UPDATE:

From @Domen: `$Post = FullSimplify[#, TimeConstraint -> 30] &;`.

Comment: ``$Post = FullSimplify;``

Comment: Be careful doing `FullSimplify` after each command. `FullSimplify` could easily end up taking very very long time since it tries many things, and your code will end up taking hrs to finish depending how long it is. I normally put `TimeConstrained` on it if I have to use it.

Comment: Often, to be fully effective, `FullSimplify` needs to be provided with appropriate assumptions.

Comment: Also, `FullSimplify` produces generically correct simplifications, which may hide issues which should be taken into account if used automatically.

Comment: To add options to ``FullSimplify`` use ``$Post = FullSimplify[#, TimeConstraint -> 30] &;``

Comment: `Block[{$Post = ... }, ...]` does not do anything because `$Post` would only be applied after the block has exited. Are you aware that you can type `// FullSimplify` directly at the end of an output, which is quite quick to do? That might be the best solution for you. I assume that by now you have tried out `$Post = FullSimplify` and discovered why it's not a practically workable solution.

Comment: Writing ```//FullSimplify``` every time is precisely what I am trying to avoid. You are right, it does not work with ```Block```, but it does work without using ```Block``` if one is careful about adding ```$Post=.``` at the end. I was just trying out a way of localizing any potential damage, in case someone forgets to add this line of code at the end.

Comment: You might want to use a wrapper `noSimplify` for computations you do not want to simplify (for example if they take too long). The wrapper `noSimplify` should not evaluate to anything. Then you can use something like `$Post = Switch[#, _noSimplify, #[[1]], _, FullSimplify[#]] &;` and use `//noSimplify` the times that you do not want to simplify the expression.

Comment: If you want to increase your chances of remembering to use `$Post=.` at the end you could include a maybe somewhat annoying message with `Print` in the `$Post` like "full simplified" so you might notice `$Post` is still modified. A more fancy approach might involve changing the front end to signal visually "full simplify mode". For example as a background color change with something like `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Background] = RGBColor[0.936608, 0.84884, 0.493779]` and a function fullSimplifyOff that uses `($Post=.;CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Background]=None)` for example

Answer (score 2):

Will it solve your difficulty if you introduce a short version of its name, like fS?

For example,

```
fS[x_, ass__ : Automatic] := FullSimplify[x, Assumptions -> ass]
```

Its use requires then much less typing. For example, this is with no assumptions:

```
(1/a - 1/(b + c))/(
  1/a + 1/(
   b + c))*(1 + (b^2 + c^2 - a^2)/(2*b*c))/((a - b - c)/(a*b*c)) // fS

(* 1/2 a (a - b - c)  *)
```

or with the assumptions:

```
(Sqrt[Sqrt[m] - Sqrt[(m^2 - 9)/m]] + Sqrt[
    Sqrt[m] + Sqrt[(m^2 - 9)/m]])^2*Power[m^2/4, (4)^-1] //fS[#, m > 0] &

(*  Sqrt[2] (3 + m)  *)
```

The analogous short-cut you might make also with the `Simplify`to avoid using `FullSimplify`everywhere.

Hope this helps. Have fun!

Comment: You seem to underestimate the @Nasser's comment.

Comment: It was not my intention. Let me edit my comment.

Comment: I think @Domen ‘s suggestion using ```$Post``` is really straight forward, and useful for prototyping. One only has to be careful about when to use it as as @Nasser and @kirma have warned. @Bob Hanlon, note that it can also be combined with $Assumptions for a very effective use.